# Regarding sub-additive sequences and Fekete's lemma

Tags: real-analysis

A non-negative sequence $\{a_n\}$ is sub-additive if $a_{m+n}\leq a_m + a_n.$ Fekete's lemma says that for any non-negative sub-additive sequence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \inf_{n} \frac{a_n}{n}.$$

Of course, one way to show this would be to show that $\frac{a_n}{n}$ is non-increasing, but I have seen no proof of Fekete's lemma like this, so I suspect this is not true. Can you give me an example of a non-negative sub-additive sequence $\{a_n\}$ for which $\frac{a_n}{n}$ is not non-increasing? Thanks!

Comment: How about $a_n=1$ if $n$ is odd, and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: @Lucia I think one wants $a_n$ to be increasing.

Comment: Thanks Lucia for the example. I believe you can make it increasing by adding your sequence to the sequence $b_n = 2n$ to get $c_n = 2n+ 1_{\mathrm{$n$ is odd}}$.

Comment: What does ''not non-increasing" mean?

Comment: Lucia: By "not non-increasing", I meant "not monotonically decreasing or constant".

Comment: How about $a_n=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ so $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,$ etc?

Comment: @Hedonist: In that case, why isn't the simple example of the parity of $n$ that I gave not enough?

Comment: Thanks Lucia. I realized my question had a trivial answer. Your example is sufficient to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another "natural" example. Fix an integer $b \ge 2$ and let $s_b(n)$ denote, for each $n \in \mathbf N^+$, the sum of the $b$-digits of $n$. Then $s_b$ is subadditive: This comes, e.g., from the first of the identities mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161960/looking-for-a-reference-to-a-classical-formula-for-the-sum-of-the-base-b-digit), together with the fact that also the fractional part is subadditive, which in turn is a consequence of the following:
$$
\forall x, y \in \mathbf R: \{x\} + \{y\} = \{x+y\} + \lfloor \{x\} + \{y\} \rfloor.
$$
Now observe that, for all $n \in \mathbf N^+$, 
$$
\frac{s_b(b^n)}{b^n} = \frac{1}{b^n} < \frac{2}{b^n+1} = \frac{s_b(b^n + 1)}{b^n + 1}.
$$
Therefore, the sequence $\mathbf N^+ \to \mathbf R: n \mapsto s_b(n)/n$ is not [eventually] non-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from nature, but for superadditive sequences.  Fekete's Lemma for superadditive sequences says 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \sup_{n} \frac{a_n}{n}.$$

For a CW complex $X$, we can look at the Lusternik-Schnirelmann category of the skeleta
$X_n$ as $n$ varies (actually, the relative category $\mathrm{cat}_X(X_n)$), and define
a sequence 
$$
\sigma_X (k) = \inf\{ n \mid \mathrm{cat}_X(X_n) \geq k \}.
$$
It can be proved that this sequence is always superadditive, and it contains lots of good information about the space $X$, so it is nice to determine -- or estimate -- the sequence if possible.

One big challenge to people studying L-S category is to determine the category of the symplectic groups $Sp(n)$.  It has been shown that for $n\geq 3$, the sequence
$\sigma_{Sp(n)}$ begins $(0,3,7,10,18,21,\ldots)$.  The ratios are
$$
3 < {7\over 2} > {10\over 3} < {18\over 4} > {21\over 5}
$$

Comment: Are the ratios $\sigma_{X}(k)/k$ _eventually_ non-increasing for $X = {\rm Sp}(n)$ or whatever?

Comment: I don't know!  The long term behavior of the sequence is unknown.  I'd love to know, for example, what that limit is.